# Let $T$ be an linear operator on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Prove that $\dim(T(U)) \geq \dim(U)- null(T)$ where $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I took a $X : U \rightarrow V$ as a linear map. Applying rank nullity theorem, you get $\dim(U) = \text{rank}(X) + \text{null}(X)$.

Now we know that range space of $X$ will be a subset of range space of $T$ as $U \subset V$. So $\dim X(U) \leq \dim T(U)$.

$\dim(U) = \dim X(U) + \text{null}(X)$ becomes

$\dim(U) \leq \dim (T(U)) + \text{null}(X)$.

We are required to prove that $\dim(T(U)) + \text{null}(T) \geq \dim(U)$

But after this I don't think we can say anything about the nullityof $T$ and of $X$, can we? This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict $T$ on $U$ then apply Rank Nullity theorem on $T|_U$ to get $\text{dim}(U)=\text{dim}(T(U))+\text{Nullity}(T|_U)$. Now $\text{ker}(T|_U)\subseteq \text{ker}(T)$ so $\text{Nullity}(T|_U)\leq \text{Nullity}(T)$. Thus $\text{dim}(U)\leq\text{dim}(T(U))+\text{Nullity}(T)$. Hence it is done.

Comment: Restricting the domain space would create a different map that is not $T$

Comment: Yes true. But what is your point?

Comment: We are supposed to use only T

Comment: No, we are not supposed to use only $T$, we are supposed to solve the problem. By the way which part of the answer you are not getting?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ and a linear operator $T : V \to V$ with a basis $\mathscr B = \{v_1, \dots, v_i \}$ of $\ker T.$ We can extend this to a basis $\mathscr B_U = \{v_1, \dots, v_i, u_{i + 1}, \dots, u_j \}$ of $U.$ Use the fact that $\mathscr B_U$ is a basis for $U$ to prove that the vectors $T(u_{i + 1}), \dots, T(u_j)$ are linearly independent, from which it follows that $\dim T(U) \geq j - i.$ But this says exactly that $\dim T(U) \geq \dim U - \dim \ker T,$ i.e., $\dim U \leq \dim \ker T + \dim T(U).$